# Redirect traffic to regional EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am quite new to AWS and would need the experienced advises. I am looking to build a SaaS on AWS which would need to redirect traffic to EC2 instances based on their region.

For example, there can be 3 regional instances like US, EU and Asia. When a traffic comes from Asia country then it will be route to Asia EC2 instance. There will be multiple Asia instances and I would need to load balance the traffic as well.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use Route 53 for your DNS resolution.

For your case, you can use Latency-Based routing. Latency-Based routing will respond to DNS queries with IP addresses that have the lowest latency to the requestor.

So using this, users will be directed to the region with the lowest latency, which in most cases is their closest region.

Comment: Thanks Matt! Let me look it up and try to implement it. By the way, if I want to set up different sub domain names for different groups of EC2 instances I would just need to set it up inside AWS right?

Comment: If you want different subdomain names tightly coupled with this solution, then the web servers need to redirect incoming requests with global hostnames back to themselves using the canonical regional hostnames.  Request for `www.example.com` arriving at an `eu.example.com` server returns `307 Moved Temporarily` `Location: https://eu.example.com`, redirecting the user to the same server but now using the correct canonical regional hostname, rewriting the browser address bar in the process.

Comment: @Norman You can set that up. You can have `www.example.com` use Latency-Based routing to get to the fastest region. And you can set `eu.example.com` to point directly to your Europe region.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That is purely dependent on the web server's configuration. You can configure your web server to accept connections from either `www` or `eu` without displaying a redirect to the browser.

Comment: @MattHouser, of course, that's true.  My comment wasn't about your +1 answer.  It was a response to the OP's comment.  The key phrase behind my thoughts when I posted that was "tightly coupled" -- if you wanted the user to see the subdomain, the server (cluster) needs to redirect the request to itself using its official regional endpoint name, if the generic name comes in on the `Host:` header, since of course latency-based routing wouldn't do that on its own so the subdomains OP mentioned would otherwise remain hidden.